# Why segmentation fault in the below C Code?

Tags: c

The problem is of left rotation in array.

The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of `n` (the number of integers) and `d` (the number of left rotations you must perform). 
The second line contains `n` space-separated integers describing the respective elements of the array's initial state.

My solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
    int n, d, i;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &d);
    int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    int *temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * d);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
        temp[i] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n - d; i++)
        a[i] = a[i + d];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i + n - d] = temp[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `scanf`; a fatal logic flaw.

Comment: What is the input? You will get always SIGSEGV when d > n.

Comment: Use a debugger. Use debug printfs. Learn basic debugging techniques (posting immediately on SO is not a great debugging technique despite what many people seem to think). And please pick only the relevant language tags. C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: You tagged this as `C++`.  If you actually used `C++` instead of `C`, using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)  and [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) makes this a 2 or 3  line program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems.

First you made implicit assertions in the code

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
for(i=0;i<d;i++)
  temp[i]=a[i];
            ^
      d should be <= n
```

that are wrong: if `d > n` you are doing a read-access out of an allocated zone.

Same problem in

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  a[i+n-d]=temp[i];
      ^         ^
2*n-d <= n and n <= d
    n >= d for i = 0
```

The code before the `malloc` calls should be executed under the condition

```
if (n > 0 && d > 0 && n < ... && d < ...)
```

I think you can assume `d = n` to write the first version of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The code always fails if `d > n`, but it also fails if `d < n`: the fourth `for` loop is incorrect, it should stop at `d`:

```
for (i = 0; i < d; i++)
    a[i + n - d] = temp[i];
```